# Check for a stale element using selenium 2?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium 2, is there a way to test if an element is stale?

Suppose I initiate a transition from one page to another (A -> B).  I then select element X and test it.  Suppose element X exists on both A and B.

Intermittently, X is selected from A before the page transition happens and not tested until after going to B, raising a StaleElementReferenceException.  It's easy to check for this condition:

```
try:
  visit_B()
  element = driver.find_element_by_id('X')  # Whoops, we're still on A
  element.click() 
except StaleElementReferenceException:
  element = driver.find_element_by_id('X')  # Now we're on B
  element.click()
```

But I'd rather do:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('X') # Get the elment on A
visit_B()
WebDriverWait(element, 2).until(lambda element: is_stale(element))
element = driver.find_element_by_id('X') # Get element on B
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you are using there but the basic idea you need in order to solve this is:

```
boolean found = false
set implicit wait to 5 seconds
loop while not found 
try
  element.click()
  found = true
catch StaleElementReferenceException
  print message
  found = false
  wait a few seconds
end loop
set implicit wait back to default
```

NOTE: Of course, most people don't do it this way.  Most of the time people use the ExpectedConditions class but, in cases where the exceptions need to be handled better
this method ( I state above) might work better.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby,

```
$default_implicit_wait_timeout = 10 #seconds

def element_stale?(element)
  stale = nil  # scope a boolean to return the staleness

  # set implicit wait to zero so the method does not slow your script
  $driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 0

  begin ## 'begin' is Ruby's try
    element.click
    stale = false
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError
    stale = true
  end

  # reset the implicit wait timeout to its previous value
  $driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = $default_implicit_wait_timeout

  return stale
end
```

The code above is a Ruby translation of the stalenessOf method provided by [ExpectedConditions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java?r=b9487ce33e056fdf318b64806c9186a050b6a7e8).  Similar code could be written in Python or any other language Selenium supports, and then called from a WebDriverWait block to wait until the element becomes stale.